# Parse CDATA with HTML tag and get contents

Tags: java, android, html, dom, xml-parsing

I am parsing RSS feed and getting **description** tag as follow.

```
        <description><![CDATA[<img width="255" height="220" src="http://test.es/wp-content/themes/prime-theme/gbs-addons/advanced-thumbnail/timthumb.php?src=http://test.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/fd_prduct03.jpg&amp;w=255&amp;h=220&amp;zc=1&amp;s=0&amp;a=0&amp;q=89&amp;cc=0000000" class="attachment-gbs_voucher_thumb wp-post-image" alt="fd_prduct03" /><p><strong>€20.00</strong></p><p>Expires On: December 31, 1969 23:59:59<br/><span>0</span> buyers!<br/>Savings: 10%of full price</p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.Nam [&#8230;]]]></description>
```

Now I want to get elements like imagelink, Savings, Expires On etc from description element.

I have tried [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180606/parsing-xml-android-description-tag-parsing)
and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193525/android-dom-parser-retrieving-image-link-from-description-tag) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

use JSoup it is great API for that